# Uniformly Resizing a set of Buttons after they are reloaded with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm facing a problem regarding gracefully resizing a set of buttons on a web page. 
My problem in detail:
I have a set of buttons which are part of a unordered list.
Eg:

```
<div id="button-set-1" height="some fixed no" width="inherited from parent">
  <ul>
    <li id="list_item_0">
      <button id="button_0">
       <div class="inner_left_div">
       </div>
       <div class="inner_right_div">
       </div>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li id="list_item_1">
      <button id="button_1">
      <div class="inner_left_div">
      </div>
      <div class="inner_right_div">
      </div>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li id="list_item_2">
      <button id="button_2">
      <div class="inner_left_div">
      </div>
      <div class="inner_right_div">
      </div>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that the right div in each of the buttons has dynamic content, fetched from AJAX and updated on some user action. The content fetched from AJAX is variable in length across the butttons. I want to maintain that ultimately all buttons have the same height and width after the content is loaded. I tried determining the max-height and width and then using jQuery to set that. But its very cumbersome and jittery because for some cases number of buttons is very high and multiple AJAX calls are required to fetch content for all buttons. Then I have to resize after every batch. 
Can someone suggest a neat way to do it, which would not be too obvious for the user and not degrade the user-experience for the web-page. Should I use animations to resize it?

Comment: You can specify the css as follows: [id^="list_item"] button div{ width: 400px; height: 300px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the height for the content inside button through css.

**CSS**

```
[id^="list_item"] button div{ 
width: 400px; height: 300px;
}
```

This selector will select all the div elements which is under buttons inside list items.

Comment: I'm getting the content through AJAX later so cannot set it earlier.

Comment: Though you are going to load the content later, if the content has the same id , then you can add this styles in your css. It will work. Because styles will be applied for the dynamic content also.

Comment: @pragya If you have any doubts you can refer the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/hLy8cpaw/

Comment: How do I determine the height? That is the problem. The AJAX content is variable across buttons and I would only know that after I have gotten the content via AJAX.